# Как создать окно в дочерном окне через кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть главное окно с кнопкой при нажатие на нее открываеться второе окно , как сделать во втором окне кнопку которая будет открывать еще одно окно

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_window():
       window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create_window(root): #лучше передать root как параметр
       window = tk.Toplevel(root)
       button = tk.Button(window,
           text="Хей, это кнопка открывает такое-же окно!",
           command=lambda:create_window(window) 
                 #если надо открыть другое окно - создайте другую функцию 
       )
       button.pack()
root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=lambda:create_window(root))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```